# How do i view data in database which i have stored in Berkeley db?

Tags: python, dictionary, cgi, berkeley-db, bsddb

I am storing a values in form of dictionary in the database. Now how do i view this data which are getting stored in this database ?? I want to list all the data stored in database. I am using Berkeley db. And using dictionary i am storing data

#!/usr/bin/python

```
import bsddb
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type:text/html\n"
Fname = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
Age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
Gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')

#print Fname, Lname, Age 

db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","w")
db['FirstName'] = Fname  
db['LastName'] = Lname
db['Age'] = Age 
db['Gender'] = Gender
db.close()
db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","r")
#db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db")
print db['FirstName'], db['LastName'], db['Age'], db['Gender']
db.close()
```

Comment: Your code already does show the data in the database. Is your question how to show _all_ the data in the database, even if you don't know ahead of time what might be there? (If not, my answer isn't relevant.)

Comment: As a side note, as the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) say right at the top, `bsddb` is "Deprecated since version 2.6". Is there a good reason to use this deprecated module in your code?

Comment: I want all the data to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you'd view data in a `dict`: by iterating it.

Some of the database modules, including `bsddb`, don't have an `__iter__` method, but they all have `keys`. So:

```
db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","r")
for key in db.keys():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, db[key]))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "viewdatabase.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ('{}:{}'.format(key, db[key]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: @user2968229: I assumed you were using Python 2.7 or 3.x, since you didn't say otherwise. If you're using a really old version of Python… you should upgrade. But if you can't, then `print '%s: %s' % (key, db[key])` instead. Or even just `print key, db[key]` if you want. You should know how to print out objects.